# relative sizes of SVG text and rect

Tags: svg

Is anyone able to offer an explanation of the change in relative size of the rect and text when adding attributes (width, height, viewBox) to the SVG element?  (tested in Firefox 30 on Linux x86_64)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <svg>
    <g transform="translate(10, 10)">
        <rect fill="yellow" height="7.45em" width="29.4em"></rect>
        <text stroke="black">
            <tspan dy="1.69em" x="2.65em">PNUUUUUUUUU</tspan>
            <tspan dy="1.69em" x="2.65em">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</tspan>
            <tspan dy="1.69em" x="2.65em">EEE</tspan>
            <tspan dy="1.69em" x="2.65em">QQQ</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

shows as desired:

[image]

changing the svg element to
`<svg width="400px" height="300px">`

or 
`<svg width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300">`

gives this result:

[image]

Comment: It seems likely it's something to do with default font face and size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://www.impressivewebs.com/understanding-em-units-css/

If you do not set font-size anywhere in your document (css or html file), then "em" will be relative to the size of font used by the web browser.

In google chrome, this is in settings under: web content -> font-size.

Comment: +1 the link mentions that 1em is not necessarily the width of M any longer.  Depending on what character is used in the example text the results are considerably different - though the width of the rect remains constant with the changes in text.  So it looks like Firefox is actually doing what it perceives as the correct thing, although if I change the font to a fixed width font (e.g. Courier) the rect doesn't change size curiously.

Comment: it would be good to put some of this information and possibly an example in your answer